# What is the difference between (EXECUTE AS SCRIPT F5) and (EXECUTE F9) in TOAD for ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, toad

What is the difference between (EXECUTE AS SCRIPT **F5**) and (EXECUTE **F9**) in TOAD ORACLE ?

Answer (score 3):

Execute (F9) only executes the statement you have selected. Execute as script (F5) executes every statement in the editor in order.

Comment: all results vs paged results, grids vs sqlplus style output...plus a few more differences